# Word, VBA: Programmatically check for certain style in range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a range. In this range is some text. Can I now detect with vba whether a certain stlye - let's say Heading1 - is used in this range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the `Selection.Find` method

```
mySelection.Find.ClearFormatting
mySelection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
With mySelection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .CorrectHangulEndings = False
        .HanjaPhoneticHangul = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
End With
mySelection.Find.Execute
```